# Find first number in a sequence that is wholly divisible by another number

Tags: f#

I'm working on a set of coding challenges. As part of that, I need to find the two numbers in a list that are evenly divisible. There will only ever be one set of numbers that fulfill this criteria.

This is the function I have right now

```
let spreadsheet (s: string) = 
    s.Split([|"\r\n"|], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) 
    |> Seq.map (fun(d: string) -> d.Split([|' '|], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) |> Seq.map Int32.Parse)

let fourthChallenge() =
    // In the real code, this reads from a file. That part works fine though.
    let input = spreadsheet "5 9 2 8\r\n9 4 7 3\r\n3 8 6 5"
    let firstEvenlyDivisable number data = data |> Seq.collect /number |> Seq.find (fun x -> box x :? int)
    let rowChecksums = input |> Seq.map (fun (row: seq<int>) -> Seq.iteri (fun i n -> firstEvenlyDivisable n (Seq.skip i row)))
    Seq.sum rowChecksums
```

The problem I'm having right now is that `firstEvenlyDivisable` seems to be a `seq<int> -> unit` instead of the `seq<int> -> int` I would expect.

When the data comes out of `Seq.collect /number` it seems to be a `seq<unit>` and I'm not clear why.

Comment: I recommend adding type annotations to help track down the problem.

Comment: @Foole Yup, looks like `iteri` doesn't return a sequence. I completely thought it did. I actually needed `mapi`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that is that `Seq.iteri` does not return the generated sequence. To return the sequence after a project function has been run on it, you want `mapi`.

You also need to explicitly pass `row` as a second argument to `Seq.mapi`.

This is the working version of the code.

```
let fourthChallenge() =
    let input = spreadsheet (readChallengeInput 3)
    let firstEvenlyDivisable number (data: seq<int> ) = data |> Seq.map (fun (i: int) -> i/number ) |> Seq.find (fun x -> box x :? int)
    let rowChecksums = input |> Seq.collect (fun (row: seq<int>) -> Seq.mapi (fun i n -> firstEvenlyDivisable n (Seq.skip i row)) row)
    Seq.sum rowChecksums
```